# Parse HTML (after submitting a form)

Tags: android, html, forms, parsing, submit

I have got a PHP/HTML page where I want to fetch data from but after submitting a form.

Like:

1. Open site
2. Input this content
3. Sumbit
4. Parse the NEW site for content

What is the fastest way to achieve this?

I began with webview - too much not needed stuff, so I changed to org.apache.http and that seemed okay.

Here is a part of my code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("WEBSITE NAME");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("THE NAME OF THE SEARCH B OX", "WORD I WANT TO BE PUT IN"));


        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();


        String sourceCode = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

So at the end the httpEntity has got the HTML - and then I'm stuck.  Is there any way how to PARSE it to get for example - find a table and get the second row's second cell's content?

Comment: I'm assuming that the website is returning HTML in some fashion - in that case I'd whip out the old trusty TagSoup library (http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) , a SAXParser implementation that is capable of reading HTML as it is encountered out in the wild - ragged, malformed and broken. Note: There's usually a TagSoup library hidden in your Android platform, so you might see some collision warnings when you build & install your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Answer (score 1):

A small and powerful library I can recommend is HtmlCleaner (106 kB, htmlcleaner.sf.net). It parses almost any HTML, no matter how ugly it is, turns it into XML, and then lets you access certain parts of it. 
They have good examples on their page, too.

Comment: I found that on google, but the problem im having here is either how to make HTML Cleaner to handle my "response - httpResponse" (no idea how to set that as source for parsing) or how to use anouther way that HTML Cleaner undersnand - but with a filled and submitted form before is starts parsing..